# Chrome Extension manifest error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I got following error `Manifest is not valid JSON.  Line: 5, column: 25, Syntax error.`

My **manifest.json** file

```
{
    "name":"webrun",
    "manifest_version":0.5.1,
    "description":"Let code run in web!",
    "browser_action":{
        "default_icon":"icon.png",
        "default_title":"webrun",
        "default_popup":"index.html"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, http://jsonlint.com/ can be used to validate any JSON files. `0.5.1` is an invalid value in JSON.

[`manifest_version` has to be an integer](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#manifest_version), it can take value 1 or 2. Check [Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html).

To specify the version of your Chrome extension, use the `"version"` key, and quote the value:

```
{
    "name": "webrun",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.5.1",
    "description": "Let code run in web!",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_title": "webrun",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    }
}
```